# How to get version of application

Tags: extjs6.5.1

How do i get the build version of my application developed using EXTJS.6.5? Is there a way to increment the version of my application programatically everytime a build is done?

Your help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: nothing for the poor :(

Comment: Any help please..